# Why isn't this threefold repetition, forcing a draw?

Tags: rules, draw, threefold-repetition

Here's my scenario, White has pawns on c2 and a2, and a king on c1, while Black has a queen on b4 and a king on d1.

```
[FEN "4k3/8/8/8/1q6/8/P1P5/2K5 b - - 0 1 "]

1...Qe1+ 2.Kb2 Qb4+ 3.Ka1 Qe1+ 4.Kb2 Qb4+.
```

Why isn't this threefold repetition? I'm the player with Black, we've been going back and forth for 30 moves. I've offered a draw and the guy won't accept. I have the weaker position on the board, which is why I want a draw. Is this just bad chess ethics on my part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as "3 move repetition". To claim a draw, the *position* must be repeated three times (although it does not have to be in a row). In your example, the position with a Black queen and b4 and a White king on b2 has only occurred twice so far. You can claim a draw by repetition of position the next time that you can cause that position to appear.

If you make such a valid claim and your opponent refuses to honor it, he or she is not playing by the rules of chess. If you are playing on some computer service that does not recognize a valid claim of threefold repetition, the service does not implement the full rules of chess.

Comment: If we're talking about chess.com, when threefold repetition does happen,exactly when it does (I did this a few times, so I'm sure it happens) you just need to click the button to offer a draw, and it will automatically end as a draw, your opponent won't be able to accept/reject. So basically at that time "draw" button stands for what should be the "claim draw" button.

Answer (score 4):

For a draw in chess any one of the following rules should satisfy :

- stalemate
- threefold repetition of a position (with the same player to move)
- if there has been no capture or a pawn being moved in the last fifty moves
- if checkmate is impossible
- or if the players agree to a draw.

The **threefold repetition rule** (also known as repetition of position) states that a player can claim a draw if the **same position** occurs three times, or will occur after their next move, with the same player to move and the same possible moves. The last means that the first time and the third time have both the same castling and en passant moves possible.

**The repeated positions do not need to occur in succession.**

**The rule applies to positions, not moves.**

*Now, analyze the moves on a board once again and see if it really was a draw.*

Answer (score 1):

You can easily win this game, you know. You can take both pawns (as white must make a move) with the queen, then get your king active and checkmate. If white refuses to give up its pawns, you can force the king away by checking constantly with the queen until he must give up the H7 pawn, and eventually the F7 pawn. It will take a while, but it is inevitable as long as you don’t blunder.

Comment: The board in the game is from Black's point of view. Those pawns are on b2 and c2, and the Black win is extremely easy. On the other hand, if it is White which is moving up the board, it isn't so easy to win. For example, if Black checks from g6 while the king is on g8, forcing Black to abandon one of the pawns, Black would happily go to h8, allowing Black to stalemate them by seizing the f7 pawn. In fact, I don't see any path to "force the king away by checking constantly with the queen until he must give up the H7 pawn".